# Proof verification of Rank Theorem in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix over $F$, where $F$ is a field.

Let $A_i$ denote $i$-th row of $A$, and let $A^j$ denote $j$-th column of $A$.

---

For $1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k \leq m$ and $1 \leq j_1 < \cdots < j_k \leq n$,
by choosing the intersection elements of $A_{i_p}$ and $A^{j_q}$,
where $1 \leq p, q \leq k$, we can make a $k \times k$ submatrix of $A$.

Think of invertible submatrices of $A$. Between them, there is a submatrices of $A$
whose dimension is maximal. Let us denote the number by $r$. We shall show that $r$ is the row rank, and column rank of $A$.

If $r = m$, then there is $m \times m$ invertible submatrix of $A$. The column rank is $m$, and the row rank is $m$.

If $r = n$, then it is showed in the same way.

If $r < m$ and $r < n$. Then the row $\{A_{i_1}, \ldots, A_{i_r}\}$ is linearly independent.
(There is some notational abuse.) Thus the row rank of $A$ is $\geq r$. And by assumption, for every $(r+1) \times (r+1)$ submatrices of $A$, it is not invertible. Hence there is no $r+1$ linearly independent rows in $\{A_1, \ldots, A_m\}$.
Thus the maximal number of linearly independent rows of $A$ is $r$.
Hence the row rank of $A$ is $r$.
Similarly, the column rank of $A$ is $r$.

---

Well, I think it is right, but there might be some jump in this proof. For example, the last part need some complementation.